# NSURL Exceptions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I am trying to grab a path value from an array for an NSURL to set an icon in my app. I get an

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5622590.

If I use an nslog I get the expected output:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[wforecast.wicons objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"nodeContent"]);
```

Which gives me:

[image]

Im setting the value as follows

```
NSURL *urlpath;

NSString *urls = [[wforecast.wicons objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"nodeContent"];

urlpath = [NSURL URLWithString:(NSString *)urls];
```

I appreciate this is a longwinded way of doing things but I was trying to break up the individual components to find out what was going wrong but I am at a loss!

Comment: Which line of code causes the crash?

Answer (score 6):

You have essentially the same problem as [this other questioner had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174315/cocoa-webkit-bug/2174877#2174877). You passed an object that is not an NSString where you needed to pass an NSString.

Use the debugger to determine exactly where the exception occurred. If you haven't done this, I wouldn't be so sure that the code you showed is what caused it; the debugger will tell you where the exception occurred with no room for doubt.

Once you've found where the exception occurred, you can examine the object that you passed, and look back at where you got it from. You need to fix either how you retrieve the string or how you stored it in the place you're now getting it from.

Comment: @user596968: That much was already in evidence from the exception message. The debugger will tell you more.